# How to determine what WiX version that was used to create a wixproj

Tags: wix

Quite simply, what the title says:  I have some old source code with a WiX installer project in it.  I'm trying to determine what Version of WiX was used to build it so I'm using the same version when I try to rebuild it.

Comment: Have you had problems building it with a newer version of WiX?

Comment: The wixproj format is pretty much independent from the WiX tools and the project's source files. The wixcop tool updates source files. So, one way to answer the question is to go back over older wixcop versions. The first one that doesn't change your source could be it. Once you figure it out, for configuration management, you could add a step that verifies the wixproj is being built with the intended/tested version of WiX.

Answer (score 6):

If you open the wixproj file into a text editor (or unload/edit in Visual Studio), you will see (or should) the following property;

```
 <ProductVersion>3.8</ProductVersion>
```

That is the only reference I could find to what I know is the version I am using.

Comment: From my experience, the <ProductVersion> tag indicates the version of the product you are creating the installer for.  There IS an attribute called "ToolsVersion" in the <Project> tag at the top of the file, but I can't tell how to relate it to the exact WiX version.  The one I have says "4.0", but there ISN'T a WiX Version 4.0 yet.

Comment: @RichStephens I believe you are referring to the <Product> element which has a "Version" attribute. This element is defined in the Product.wxs file by default. What ChrisBint is referring to is defined in the WIXPROJ file of the project.

It looks like the ProductVersion in the WIXPROJ does indicate the version of WiX, but not exactly. For example, when i created a WiX project using WiX version 3.11.0.1701, the ProductVersion was 3.10, so I am not sure if this very helpful, but it can narrow things down a little.